# A computation in Conrey's paper on Riemann zeta function

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions, riemann-hypothesis

I am reading the Conrey's paper "More than two fifths of the zeros of the Riemann zeta function are on the critical line" (see [here](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/crll.1989.issue-399/crll.1989.399.1/crll.1989.399.1.xml)).
I have question/doubt in a particular step: In P.10, it claimed that $B=0$. I wonder why it is true, because, in my opinion, there should be an extra term coming from the integration by parts: 
$$B=\theta\int_0^1 w(y)\overline{w}'(y)dy
=\theta\int_0^1 e^{2Ry}[R(1+\lambda y)^2+\lambda(1+\lambda y)]dy\\
=\theta\left(\int_0^1 e^{2Ry}R(1+\lambda y)^2dy+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1e^{2Ry}d((1+\lambda y)^2)\right)\\
\\
=\theta \Bigg[\frac{1}{2}e^{2Ry}(1+\lambda y)^2\Bigg]_{y=0}^{y=1},$$
where the last equality follows from doing integration by parts. I think this paper have been read and checked by many people. I would appreciate if I can get help from some of you who are familiar with this paper. Thank you very much.

Comment: I cannot access the paper. The only thing I could say is that your integration is perfect. Now, the stupid question : is there any relation between $R$ and $\lambda$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks for the comment. But it seems that $R$ and $\lambda$ are not related. In P.10 of the paper, it was chosen such that $R=1.2$ and $\lambda=-1.02$, and it does not make the above term vanishes. I am not sure if I miss something.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316712/a-computation-in-conreys-paper-on-riemann-zeta-function